# Casperjs Fill Method make next function only run after the previouse function has finished

Tags: javascript, casperjs

heres my casperjs script

```
var ccommss = require('node_modules/ccomms');
var system = require('system');
var casper = require('casper').create({
    logLevel: "debug",
    waitTimeout: 10,
    stepTimeout: 10,
    verbose: true,
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1280,
        height: 960
    },
    pageSettings: {
        "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1262.0 Safari/537.10',
        "webSecurityEnabled": false,
        "ignoreSslErrors": true
    },
    onWaitTimeout: function () {
        // casper.capture('./out/wait-timeout:_' + TimeTidy() + '.png');
        // throw new Error stuff;
    },
    onStepTimeout: function () {
        // casper.capture('./out/step-timeout' + TimeTidy() + '.png');
        // throw new Error stuff;
    }
});


var Visit = "https://example.com/login.html";
var use = {};
casper.start(Visit, function () {

    casper.then(function () {
        ccommss.CaptchaGet();
    });

    casper.then(function () {
        ccommss.Login();
        console.log(use.name + " " + use.pass + " " + use.turing);
    });

    casper.then(function () {
        this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
    });

});

casper.run();
```

the problem is when i run the ccommss.Login() function i have built wich is below 
the casper.then statment this.getcurrenturl() is ran before the page redirects

heres is my function

```
exports.Login = function() {

var line = system.stdin.readLine();
    var split = line.split (':');
    casper.fill('form[name="reg"]', {
           'login': split[0],
           'password': split[1],
           'turing': split[2]
        }, false);
casper.click("input#sbt.submit[type='submit']");

return use.name = split[0],
       use.pass = split[1],
       use.turing = split[2];



};
```

problem is when this runs

```
    casper.then(function () {
        this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
    });
```

it is useless as this function is still working

```
ccommss.Login();
```

and the url change has not happend yet 
i know i may be able to fix it with a callback of somekind can anybod help me fix this please

Comment: you could use [waitForUrl](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforurl)function to make sure that url is changed.

Comment: i cannot use that as it may change to any oneof 4 diffrent urls randomly

Comment: If there is a way to pass an url to casper.start, then i assume you could pass the same url to casper.waitForUrl without hardcoding it ?

Comment: no i cannot pass the same url as it may be on of 3 difffrent urls that i have know way off knowing until that function is complete hence why i am thinking making the function using a callback is that possible

Comment: So if i get it right, then you start the navigation at `https://example.com/login.html` and submitting the form can result in  3 possible url's ?

Answer (score 1):

You set stepTimeout to 10 milli seconds. It is just not enough time to process anything in the login step. So my guess is that the login step is aborted and the next step is executed. By default the script would `die`, but you provided a stepTimeout callback which disables the `die()`.

Solution would be to increase the timeout to something like 5 seconds (**5000**). Btw, `waitTimeout` is also too short.